# How to sum columns horizontally with arrayformula based on what is in the column header?

Tags: google-sheets, pivot, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I would like to sum row values based on column headers condition, like on the screenshot, but I would like to have an automatically extended arrayformula so the formula is only in G1 and H1.

[image: How sum rows with arrayformula based on what is in the column header?]

Comment: Hi welcome to SOF please share your approach of solving this, what did you try? what is the current formulas?

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add input table and expected output table to the question. Use [Markdown Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892)-all the data needed to answer your question must be in the question itself. [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and tips guys. Will include my progress next time. Also thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
={BYROW(FILTER(A2:E10, A1:E1="A"), LAMBDA(xx, SUM(xx))), 
  BYROW(FILTER(A2:E10, A1:E1="B"), LAMBDA(xx, SUM(xx)))}
```

[image]

Comment: Add this as option 2 to match the first letter `REGEXMATCH($A$1:$E$1, REGEXEXTRACT(G1, "."))`,  I did the same and now I want to get `""` after the last value is the is a simple way? should I post as a question? like when non empty max row do nothing.

Comment: Something like this `=BYROW(A2:E ,LAMBDA(rg,SUMPRODUCT(rg)<>0))`  - @player0

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for. I am amazed how short is the formula that does the job. Never used lambda and byrow before. Will look them up now to learn more about them.

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula **to eliminate `0`'s after the last value.**

```
=ArrayFormula({ 
 IF(IF(ROW(A2:E)<=MAX(IF(A2:E="",,ROW(A2:E))),1,0)<>1,,
    BYROW($A$2:$E, LAMBDA(rg, SUMIF(IFERROR(REGEXMATCH($A$1:$E$1, REGEXEXTRACT(G1, ".")),""), true, rg)))),
 IF(IF(ROW(A2:E)<=MAX(IF(A2:E="",,ROW(A2:E))),1,0)<>1,,
    BYROW($A$2:$E, LAMBDA(rg, SUMIF(IFERROR(REGEXMATCH($A$1:$E$1, REGEXEXTRACT(H1, ".")),""), true, rg))))})
```

[image]

### Short version without spilling `0`'s

```
=ArrayFormula(LAMBDA(r,h, { 
 IF(IF(ROW(r)<=MAX(IF(r="",,ROW(r))),1,0)<>1,,
    BYROW(r, LAMBDA(r, SUMIF(REGEXMATCH(h, "A"), true, r)))),
 IF(IF(ROW(r)<=MAX(IF(r="",,ROW(r))),1,0)<>1,,
    BYROW(r, LAMBDA(r, SUMIF(REGEXMATCH(h, "B"), true, r))))})(A2:E,A1:E1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`TRANSPOSE` the array and use `QUERY` to `group by` the first `Col` and `sum` the remaining columns.

```
=TRANSPOSE(
  QUERY(
    QUERY(
      TRANSPOSE(A1:E5),
      "select Col1,sum(Col"&JOIN("),sum(Col",SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1:E5)-1,1,2))&") group by Col1",
      0
    ),
  "offset 1",0)
)
```

##### Advantages:

- `QUERY` is faster
- Supports unlimited number of headers, not just `A` and `B`